# Velocity controll and PID tuneing

Tags: ros, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently building a simulation model for my robot and so far almost every thing works. I can move all my actuators. I'm currently stuck with the controlling the wheel velocity.

I have a joint

```
   <joint name="wheel_main_rotation" type="continuous">
      <parent link="wheel_main_suspension" />
      <child link="wheel_main" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
      <limit effort="2000.0" velocity="1.0" />
   </joint>
```

with a transmission

```
   <transmission name="tran2">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="wheel_main_rotation">
         <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor2">
         <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
         <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>
```

with the following controller config

```
  # velocity Controllers ---------------------------------------
  joint2_velocity_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: wheel_main_rotation
    pid: {p: 10000.0, i: 1.0, d: 1000.0}
```

and a rosnode which publishes the value `1.0` on the following topic

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('/my_robot_ns/joint2_velocity_controller/command', Float64, queue_size=10)
```

This approach works for all my `revoloute` and `prismatic` joints, but not for controlling the velocity of the main wheel. I actually doesn't move at all, no matter which value I publish.

**edit:**

the maximum velocity of my robot should be 1.0 m/sec

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273259/velocity-controll-and-pid-tuneing/) by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. I needed to change the joint interface

```
   <transmission name="tran2">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="wheel_main_rotation">
         <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor2">
         <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
         <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>
```

and in the config file the controller

```
  steer_velocity_controller:
    type: velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: wheel_main_steer
    pid: {p: 10000.0, i: 1.0, d: 1000.0}
```

---

Originally posted by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) with karma: 165 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on 2019-12-17**:
^wont work for tuning pid
Error of No p gain specified still exist.

**Comment by [jaiswalharsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/56717/jaiswalharsh/) on 2020-07-29**:
I have the same error with velocity_controllers saying No p gain specified. Did you manage to solve it?